# Unable to add data to front-end of access database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a 2010 Access Database that I split for so multiple users can use the database at the same time. However, now I can't add data to the front-end through tables, queries, anything. When I go to the back-end it says it's read only and I can't add data or modify design there either, and yes I have proper permissions to view everything. I even tried setting the permissions to Everyone with Full access but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear. I'm not talking about adding a new table, but adding data into existing tables and queries. When I right click on a table row the New Record option is greyed out.

Comment: Update:
I found the reason why I couldn't edit or add data. Another user was using their front end copy. But isn't the point of a split data base so multiple users can have their own copy to add and view data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the back end db file, Access must be able to create a lock file, or update the lock file if one already exists.  When neither happens, the db file will be opened read-only.

That requirement applies when you open the back end db file directly in an Access session.  It also applies when you open the back end *indirectly* from your front end database.

The lock file uses the same base name as your db file, but a different file name extension: .ldb for an MDB db; or .laccdb for an ACCDB db.

Make sure your users have permission to create and delete files in the folder where the back end db file is located.  Alternatively, you could just give them modify permission for the lock file once it has been created.

If the problem is not a lock file issue, open one of your linked tables in datasheet view from the front end and see whether you can make changes (add and delete rows, and update values in existing rows).  If the linked tables are treated as read-only, delete the links and recreate them.  Make sure to inform Access which field or combination of fields to use as a primary key.  In the absence of that information, Access will link the tables read-only.

If the linked tables are not read-only, inspect your forms' record sources and other properties.  Some queries can still be read-only even though their source tables are editable.  And the Data tab of a form's property sheet includes properties such as Allow Additions, Allow Deletions, and Add Edits ... which influence the types of changes which can be made through that form.

Finally, make sure all front end users have default open mode set as shared.  If any user's open mode is set as exclusive, all later users can only open read-only.